# Determine average number of roll to get 1-1 on a pair of dice

Tags: python, random, nested-loops, dice, cumulative-sum

Roll a pair of 6-sided dice (a.k.a. D6) until they both come up '1'.  Count the number of rolls this took.
Run 100 trials of this.  Print out the result of each roll and report the average number of rolls required.

Use nested loops.  The outer loop runs 100 trials; the inner loop continues rolling until 1-1 appears.  Then update the running counts and go to the next trial.

```
import random
dice1, dice2 = " ", " " 
roll = " "

for roll in range(1, 101):
    roll = 0
    dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print(dice1, ",", dice2)
    while dice1 == 1 and dice2 == 1:
         break
```

this doesn't stop when 2 1's a rolled and i need help accumulating the roll number and trial number

Comment: The `break` only breaks out of the `while` loop you have. I assume you want an if statement.

Comment: Why are you initializing the variables to strings if you later assign numbers to them?

Comment: Once this is resolved for you, please remember to "accept" your favourite answer.  This properly closes the issue for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your inner loop really doesn't do anything.
You have to give it the work you described: keep rolling two dice until they both come up 1.  I'll outline the logic you described, but have trouble implementing.  I'll leave the detailed work to you.  :-)

```
roll_count = 1
while not (dice1 == 1 and dice2 == 1):
    roll both dice
    increment roll_count

running_total += roll_count
```

You also need to initialize running_total somewhere.

Does this get you unstuck?

Comment: thank you for answering! i definitely understand now!

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
from itertools import count
for roll in range(1, 101):
    for c in count(1):
        dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(c, ':', dice1, ",", dice2)
        if dice1 == 1 and dice2 == 1:
            break
```